# create a table using divs only

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs and I cannot change the html dom:

```
<div id="a"/>
<div id="b"/>
<div id="c"/>
```

I need to create css file that displays those divs like the following table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="a"></td>
    <td rowspan="2" id="c"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="b"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: a lot depends on the circumstances: 1) does the `table` have fixed width/height? 2) does the content need to be centered?

Comment: Are these 3 `<div>` tags wrapped in something?

Comment: I think you've explained this well, but just want to make sure i'm looking at this correctly...the contents in div "a" should be formatted as if they were in td "a" and same for the other divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the first two `div`s `display:inline-block` to keep them on the same line. Make the bottom `div` the width of the top two plus padding.

Sorry for a bit vague.
Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/3ZWGx/4/

--Fixed--

Comment: i think you misread the question, the table contains a rowspan, not a colspan

Comment: Sorry about that, it should work the way you described now. `:)`

Comment: This method only works for fixed width and height.  The table in the OP example will allow anything to go into any of the three cells and have the other cells adjust accordingly.

Comment: @Ghodmode: Can't I use height and width with percentage?

Comment: @Naor you can use height and width percentage, but that's still fixed as a percentage of the containing block's size.  If the container doesn't have a fixed size, the percentage would be ignored.  If you change the containing block to `display:table`, then it would act more like a table and the containing block wouldn't need a fixed size, but that solution isn't represented by this jsfiddle.  That's represented in the solution I provided.

Comment: @Ghodmode: It works if I put percentage width all over the page (including html tag).

Answer (score 0):

Use the css display: 
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#table
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

It works in IE8+.

You have e.g. display:table, table-cell or table-column.

Unfortunatelly, the rowspan is not supported, but you can embed another div in it and emulate it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all three divs are surrounded by a container and that these can be rendered at a fixed width, [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6drVC/) shows an approach using absolute positioning.  Here's the code  inline:

Markup (note, that some browsers don't render shortcut divs correctly):

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="b"></div>
    <div id="c"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

#a
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

#b
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}

#c
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although there's a little extra spacing around the cells on the left, this gives similar presentation to what you're looking for:
[demo at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qYhST/)

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #divtable {
        display: table;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border: 1px outset black;
        border-spacing: 2px;
    }
    #d, #e, #f {
        display: table-cell;
        border: 1px inset black;
        padding: 2px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .row1, .row2 {
        display: table-row;
    }

    .cell_f {
        display: table-cell;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="divtable">
    <div class="cell_de">
        <div class="row1">
            <div id="d">D</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row2">
            <div id="e">E</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="f">F</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It should be noted that `display: table-cell`, etc. is not compatible with older versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

What is required in addition to the code above to run these?  I copied this into an html document and all I got was 3 rows.